# R: Add column to several files in folder and save

Tags: r, function, csv, lapply

I am trying to apply the same function to all csv files (identical structure) in a folder - adding two new columns based on 'old' columns, adding 0.05 to each variable and then saving it under the same name in the same folder as csv. Should be easy and there are several examples here for doing that, mostly using lapply, however, I keep running into an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "LAT", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 3
```

This is my code:

```
my_files <- list.files(path="C:/PATH", pattern=".csv", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
add_col <- function(my_files) {
  mpa <- read.csv(my_files, header=T)
  mpa$LAT <- mpa$lat_bin + 0.05
  mpa$LON <- mpa$lon_bin + 0.05
  return(mpa)
  write.csv(mpa, 
            append = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE,
            sep = ",",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = TRUE)
}
```

I am unsure how best to do that for a large amounts of files.

Here is some sample code for the files

```
Df1 <- data.frame(lat_bin = c(50,40,70,6,8,4),lon_bin = (c(1,5,2,4,9,11)))
Df2 <- data.frame(lat_bin = c(66, 77, 82, 65, 88, 43),lon_bin = (c(2,3,4,5,11,51)))
Df3 <- data.frame(lat_bin = c(43,46,55,67,1,11),lon_bin = (c(7,6,5,9,11,15)))
write.csv(Df1, "data_1.csv", row.names=F)
write.csv(Df2, "data_2.csv", row.names=F)
write.csv(Df3, "data_3.csv", row.names=F)
```

Comment: Could you post an example of one of the files?

Comment: Also, please add the code you use for the task.  That kind of error isn't very useful on its own.

Comment: Where is your `lapply` call? By itself, posted code should not do anything.

Comment: @Parfait, I know `lapply` can be used for it but so far I could not make it work and don't really understand it - therefore I tried to do it just using a function

Comment: But where do you call the function? You only assign it here. What produces the error?

Comment: I tried to call it with `res <- lapply(my_files, function(add_col))` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change parameters where function receives one file and you pass entire list of files inside `lapply`. As info, `lappy` is perhaps most popular of the apply family of functions that receives a list/vector input and returns an equal-length list where each input list element is passed into a function.

Specifically here *res* returns a list of dataframes equal to the number of files in *my_files*, each with column value changes. Also, `write.csv` had a missing file name, but below saves new csv files with _new suffix (double slashes to escape period, special character in regex).

```
my_files <- list.files(path="C:/PATH", pattern=".csv", full.names=T, 
                       recursive=FALSE)

add_col <- function(one_file) {
  mpa <- read.csv(one_file, header=T)
  mpa$LAT <- mpa$lat_bin + 0.05
  mpa$LON <- mpa$lon_bin + 0.05
  write.csv(mpa, 
            file = sub("\\.csv", "_new\\.csv", one_file),
            append = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE,
            sep = ",",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = TRUE)
  return(mpa)
}

res <- lapply(my_files, function(i) add_col(i))    # LONGER VERSION
res <- lapply(my_files, add_col)                   # SHORTER VERSION
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code! I'm getting a couple of warning messages that the setting for the write.csv are ignored but it seems to be working just fine. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Try removing the *sep* argument as it is redundant for `write.csv` (always commas); it is usually used for the general `write.table`.